# No puedo castear una clase

Tags: java, android, poo

Tengo esta clase

```
public class MasterData {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String _id;
    public boolean isMp;


    @Expose(deserialize = true, serialize = false)
    public String type;
    //...metodos get y set}
```

y luego tengo esta otra que herera de `MasterData`

```
public class ArticleApplication extends MasterData {

    @SerializedName("version_borrado")
    private String versionBorrado;

    @SerializedName("ha")
    private Float ha;

    @SerializedName("active")
    private String active;
//...metodos getter an setter}
```

En otra parte del código tengo una `List` de MasterData que cuando intento recorrer me da un error de que no se puede hacer casting:

Este es trozo de código:

```
List<MasterData> articulosAux = MasterDataService.getMasterDatabytype();
  for (MasterData md : articulosAux) {
                ArticleApplication articleApplication =(ArticleApplication)md;//ERROR
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Aqui esta el error:

> at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>
> > Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> >     es.xxxxx.xxxxx.data.master.model.MasterData cannot be cast to
> >     es.xxxx.xxxxx.data.master.model.ArticleApplication

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que aparece? ¿En tiempo de compilación o de corrida?

Comment: Incluye el stacktrace completo del error por favor.

Comment: añado el error que me sale

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas queriendo hacer un casting de un objeto cuya instancia NO es un `ArticleApplication`, probablemente sea de la instancia `MasterData`.

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
List<MasterData> articulosAux = MasterDataService.getMasterDatabytype();
 for (MasterData md : articulosAux) {
     if(md instanceof ArticleApplication) {
            ArticleApplication articleApplication =(ArticleApplication)md;
     }
  }
```

De esta manera te aseguras que el objeto sea de la instancia `ArticleApplication` y evitas un `CastClassException`.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: no me funciona sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Te aseguraste de poner el `if(md instanceof ArticleApplication)` ? Por otro lado podras pasar la seccion de código donde estás seteando los articulos a tu lista `List<MasterData> articulosAux`?

Comment: List<MasterData> articulosAux = MasterDataService.getMasterDatabytype();
  for (MasterData md : articulosAux) {
                ArticleApplication articleApplication =(ArticleApplication)md;//ERROR
}

Comment: no entra dentro del if osea que md no es instancia de articleApplication, es MasterData